# Creating a Model in Rails within the controller of a different Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to implement a quote saving feature in a Rails app. I have a User Model that has_many :quotes and a Quote Model that belongs_to :user. Now I have a separate Book Model that would be the source of these quotes.

Within the Book's show.html.erb file, I have a form to save quotes for the current user

```
<%= form_for (@new_quote) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :book_id, :value => @new_comment.book_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :body %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And in the Book controller, I have

```
def show
    @new_quote = current_user.quotes.create(book_id: params[:id])
end
```

The quote saves fine but the problem is, since I have this Quote creation statement in the show method, everytime I go to the show.html.erb page of my Book model, it creates a Quote with an empty body.

What can I do to solve this? I was thinking it probably would involve moving this Quote creation to the actual create method of the Quote controller but I don't know how to exactly pass the parameters through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just [`build`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-build-attributes) that quote, but not save it to the database. Then the user need to send the form to save that record. Just change your `show` method to:

```
def show
  @new_quote = current_user.quotes.build(book_id: params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Hm I tried that and it seems to save everything but the id of the current_user. So when I look at current_user.quotes, the new quote doesn't show up.

Comment: Nevermind, I found out I just had to add another hidden field to the form which passed in the current_user id. Thanks!